# Linked list of edges

Tags: c, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

I am using an Adjacency list to construct a directed graph. I have the vertexs working properly but when it comes to making a vertex have more than one edge I am having trouble. I am also unsure of how to correctly travese through multiple edges for the purpose of printing the adjacency list. What I have at the moment is causing a segmentation fault but I would like to figure out how to correctly build the list first. I will include the main, header file, test data, and the output I am receiving.I can post the other two functions if requested. The section of code that I feel the problem is occurring in is right after I call adjListLocate twice and I am dealing with edges. I am trying to make a new edge and have it point to the old one and then have the vertex point to the new edges but that isn't happening.

main.c

```
#include "my.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{



VERTEX *adjList;
adjList  = (VERTEX*)calloc(26, sizeof(VERTEX));
//adjList = malloc(sizeof(VERTEX)*26);
FILE* p;
char a;
char b;
int check1 = 0;
int check2 = 0;
int size = 0;
int i;
int aloc = 0;
int bloc = 0;
//Statements





if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

if ((p = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading \n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}




while(fscanf(p," %c %c", &a, &b) == 2)  
{
printf("a: %c b: %c\n",a,b);

    check1 = adjListSearch(a,size,adjList);

    if(check1==1)
    {
        printf("Adding a = %c\n", a);
        adjList[size++].c = a;  
    }   
    check2 = adjListSearch(b,size,adjList);
    if(check2==1)
    {
        printf("Adding b = %c\n", b);
        adjList[size++].c = b;
    }

    aloc = adjListLocate(a,size,adjList);
    bloc = adjListLocate(b,size,adjList);

EDGE* e = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
e->v = &adjList[bloc];
if(*&adjList[aloc].p)
    {
    EDGE* f = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
    f->v = &adjList[bloc];
    f->q = (*&adjList[aloc]).p;
    (*&adjList[aloc]).p = f;

    printf("Edge Test: %c %c %c\n", f->v->c, f->q->v->c, f->q->v->c);
    }
else
{
(*&adjList[aloc]).p = e;
e->q = NULL;
}



}
//End While

printf("Size: %d\n", size);

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
printf(" %c", adjList[i].c);
    if(adjList[i].p)
    {
    VERTEX* z = (VERTEX*)malloc(sizeof(VERTEX));
    EDGE* temp = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
    z = &adjList[i];
    //printf("Edge: %c\n", z->p->v->c);
    temp = z->p;
        while(temp->v->c)
        {
        printf("test\n");   
        printf("Edge: %c\n", temp->v->c);
        temp = temp->q;
            printf("test2\n");

        }
    }
printf("\n");
}



fclose(p);


return 0;
}
//End main
```

my.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* Forward declaration */
struct EDGETAG;

typedef struct
{
    char c;
    bool isVisited;
    struct EDGETAG* p;
} VERTEX;


typedef struct EDGETAG
{
    VERTEX* v;
    struct EDGETAG* q;
} EDGE;


int main (int argc, char* argv[]);

int adjListSearch (char a, int size, VERTEX* adjList);

int adjListLocate (char a, int size, VERTEX* adjList);
```

data

```
A B
C C
E X
C D
C F
C X
```

sample output

```
a: A b: B
empty
Adding a = A
not found B
Adding b = B
a: B b: C
found B
not found C
Adding b = C
a: E b: X
not found E
Adding a = E
not found X
Adding b = X
a: C b: D
found C
not found D
Adding b = D
a: C b: F
found C
not found F
Adding b = F
Edge Test: F D D
a: C b: X
found C
found X
Edge Test: X F F
Size: 7
 Atest
Edge: B
test2
Segmentation fault
```

The edge test is what I am worried about here. I would want it to say Edge Test: X F D

Comment: here `if(*&adjList[aloc].p)` what do you expect `*&` will give ? and later what are those `*&` for ?

Comment: I think I was trying to do something with the pointers when I wrote those, I am a bit rusty with C. I just removed them and it didn't change anything. They end up canceling each other out don't they?

Comment: They cancel each other, but it makes your code very unclear, avoid unnecessary code. Also regarding "I would want it to say Edge Test: X F D" , you print `f->q->v->c` twice : `printf("Edge Test: %c %c %c\n", f->v->c, f->q->v->c, f->q->v->c);`  so it looks like it gives you what you asked for

Comment: Wow I can't believe that I didn't realize that I had the same thing there twice. Thanks for the help and I have removed the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(*&adjList[aloc].p)
{
      EDGE* f = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
      f->v = &adjList[bloc];
      f->q = (*&adjList[aloc]).p;
      (*&adjList[aloc]).p = f;

      printf("Edge Test: %c %c %c\n", f->v->c, f->q->v->c, f->q->v->c);
}
```

The above piece of code looks to me problematic. as `*&` is redundant, and the condition is simply

```
 if(adjList[aloc].p)
```

then it will always give `true` as you don't initialize `adjList[aloc].p` with `NULL`, at least i don't see where you do it. And ofcourse the

```
 printf("Edge Test: %c %c %c\n", f->v->c, f->q->v->c, f->q->v->c);
```

simply prints `f->q->v->c` twice.

Comment: So when I initially put a vertex into adjList I should set its pointer to NULL? ex. adjList[size].p = NULL;

Comment: Actually i see now that you use calloc while creating adjList, so most probably your pointers are already `NULL`, but maybe not, as there is no guarantee that `NULL` represented as 'all bit zero value'. Use malloc and then iterate over all elements and set `p` with `NULL` explicitly